# All I want to do is send text to my Arduino and display it on an LCD Screen via Serial

Tags: serial, character-lcd, oled

I have been working on this for hours and have no idea where the issue is...

So I have the following code...which when I type a letter into the Serial Monitor I get the binary code for that letter on my LCD Screen...

```
#include <Adafruit_CharacterOLED.h>
Adafruit_CharacterOLED lcd(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
void setup() 
{
    // Print a message to the LCD.
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() {
  char TestData;
  if(Serial.available() )
  {
    TestData = Serial.read();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print (TestData, BIN);  // echo the incoming character to the LCD
  }
}
```

The issue I am having is, how do I then convert the text from either BIN or HEX or some other ASCII code to literal TEXT...

I have tried leaving the `lcd.print` as simply `lcdprint (TestData)` because then it should return just the `VAL` of the input but it does not, it gives me a few weird symbols and then turns off...Like something is wrong

I also need to then figure out Char Arrays but Ill get to that once I figure out how to display a freakin LETTER

EDIT: 
https://vimeo.com/61851351 This is video of what of comparison of `lcd.print (TestData, BIN);` vs `lcd.print (TestData);`

Per the last comment the follow works as expected:

```
#include <Adafruit_CharacterOLED.h>
Adafruit_CharacterOLED lcd(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
void setup() 
{
    // Print a message to the LCD.
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  char TestData='X';
  lcd.print(TestData);
}

void loop() {
  char TestData;
  if(Serial.available() )
  {
    TestData = Serial.read();
    lcd.setCursor(8, 0);
    lcd.print (TestData, BIN);  // echo the incoming character to the LCD
  }
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  int charcode = 65;
  lcd.print(charcode);
}
```

Comment: `lcdprint (TestData)` _should_ echo the character itself, and `lcd.print (TestData, BIN);` _should_ print the ASCII of the character in binary.  Have you tried `lcd.print("hello OLED World");`?  Does it work?  If not, then the OLED display must not be hooked up correctly or is defective.

Comment: `lcd.pring("hello etc."); works fine, the issue is without the bin, it literally just sort of flashes but doesnt print the key I am pressing with the serial monitor...ill upload a video

Comment: Sorry, so `lcd.print(TestData);` fails, but `lcd.print(TestData, BIN);` prints ones and zeros?  Or both print garbage and cause shutoff? Also, if `lcd.print("Hello");` works OK in `setup()`, try putting `char TestData='X'; lcd.print(TestData);` in setup() as well, to see if it is just a `loop(...)` issue.

Comment: What you said is correct...I will try this, uploading a video of the issue now

Comment: Perhaps make the video not private?

Comment: Sorry fixed...it defaults to that on my account

Comment: From the video it appears that neither `BIN`, nor straight-up `print(char)` does what you expect.  Yet `print("Hello World");` is OK.  Have you tried `print(char)` outside of `loop`?

Comment: Well Bin atleast gives me the binary code without it glitching out...but I did what you suggested which is put char TestData='X' and print in setup and that worked fine

Comment: But to answer your question neither Bin now pring(char) within my loop does not do what I want it to

Comment: What if you put `delay(1000);` in your loop?

Comment: That did the trick...Got it to show up, thanks mate

Comment: Excellent! I don't know whether to put this in an "answer" so we can close the issue. What do people think?

Comment: As an aside I was wondering if too frequent updates were a problem, but that would mean that `serial.available()` was always returning `true`, which would be weird. So still some debugging to do, but at least the first part got solved.

Comment: Thanks mate, please do submit as answer and I will accept it, I am now asking a new question, I got a little further and am now working on importing serial data from applescript

Comment: Someone care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recap what was done to partially solve the problem:

1. Verify that `lcd.print("Hello, World");` worked OK in `setup()`
2. Tried to do `print(char);` in setup: that worked fine.  The conclusion from this was that something was going wrong in the `loop()`
3. Put `delay(1000);` inside loop(): now the characters showed up correctly on the OLED display.

This suggests that `Serial.available()` was always returning non-zero for some reason, so that is something that still needs to be looked at.  Most likely the characters coming in from the serial port were **spaces** since most of the time nothing was visible on the OLED display.